# Conditionally include project based on path

Tags: .net, msbuild

I have this:

```
MyProject/
  Common/
    Common.csproj
  Main/
    Libs/
      Utils/
        Utils.csproj
      Legacy/
        Legacy.csproj
    Server/
      Server.csproj
    Directory.Build.props
```

I want all projects in `Main/` to include the `Common` project.

So `Directory.Build.props` has this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="../../Common/Common.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

So the `Server` project includes the `Common` project as it is two levels down. But the projects in `Libs/` can't include it as it is three levels down.

I need to do something like this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="../../Common/Common.csproj" Condition="if 2 levels up is 'MyProject'"/>
  <ProjectReference Include="../../../Common/Common.csproj" Condition="if 3 levels up is 'MyProject'"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

What do I put in `Condition`? I know I need to use `MSBuildThisFileDirectory` but unsure how.

Comment: Why don't you use the solution directory as base path rather than using relative paths?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'm using dotnet core and vscode. There's no solution directory - i.e. there's no `MyProject.sln` file. Just a directory in which there are project directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="../../Common/Common.csproj" Condition="Exists('../../Common')'"/>
  <ProjectReference Include="../../../Common/Common.csproj" Condition="Exists('../../../Common')'"/>
</ItemGroup>
```